# Name of the users which executed a command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get the name of the users which executed a command (for example `cat`).

`fc -l` will provide a list with the most recent commands executed by the current user but is there an way to find out the history for all users?
I read the manual but i could not find something that would help

Do you know any other commands which would do this job?
I also tried `w` and `who`

I found this solution: the super user will search in each dir from "home" in the .bash_history and make a grep on that file for that command. It will work but is this optimal?

Comment: You may need to work with `audit` daemon.

Comment: The super user *could* search the correct history file for each user, but this assumes the user hasn't disabled history for his/her shell or saved that history in an alternate location. A better question may be: *why* do you want this information? You might restrict access to a particular command so that it requires `sudo` to run it, in which case you can log usage explicitly.

Comment: Maby if I tell some users that they are not allowed to use a command but i do not disable it because I want to see those who did not respect this rule .

Comment: to do it in a really foolproof way you could move the program into a new directory which is readable only by root. Then you write a setuid program owned by root. This program simply opens the read-only directory, logs the execution of the program (uid, date/time and argument list), sets it's user id to the original user and then runs the original program.  Simple :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) =)

```
awk -v monitoredcmd=cat '
    $1~"^#[0-9]{10,}\s*$"{
        sub(/#/,"")
        tmpdate=$1
    }
    $1==monitoredcmd{
        "date -d @"tmpdate | getline date
        close("date -d @"tmpdate) 
        print "command [" $0 "] by",
            gensub(/\/home\/([^\/]+).*/, "\\1", "", FILENAME),
            at,
            date
    }
' /home/*/.bash_history
```

### Sample Output

```
command [cat file.txt] by sputnick  mer. févr. 13 15:34:44 CET 2013
command [cat l.py] by sputnick  mer. févr. 13 15:45:38 CET 2013
command [cat foobar.pl] by marc  mer. févr. 13 15:47:54 CET 2013
```

Comment: Added `close()` to avoid the following error : `gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/home/sputnick/.bash_history FNR=5178) fatal: cannot open pipe `date -d @1361982168' (Too many open files)`

Comment: + added version with `monitoredcmd` argument variable

Comment: Version edited, performing the `date` only when needed now...

Comment: In the version of bash I have, it only writes to `.bash_history` when either the buffer becomes full or the user logs out.  `~/.bash_history` is only the default, what if the user changes the file using variable `HISTFILE`?  See also HISTCONTROL and HISTIGNORE.